# "That's graduation sorted". What type of grammar is used here?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

> That's graduation sorted.

Context: Speakers talk about the way they want to organise their graduation ceremony and finally find the perfect solution for that.

Even though I get the gist, I don't quite understand the pattern of this sentence or is it an example of some kind of idiom?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Please write a proper comment. It is hard to tell exactly what your comment is asking.

Comment: @JamesK That seems to be standard language from one of the review queues (perhaps the "first questions" queue?), as I'm sure you know. One issue that requires additional details is that the author didn't cite the source of the text. Is it something he or she made up? Something that his or her friends said? Something from a movie or TV show? Etc. (This question also has other problems IMO.)

Comment: @James K Indeed, the above is a standard, canned comment, available to reviewers in the review queue. Personally i prefer to attach my username to review comments, but by default the SE system attributes all such comments to the community bot. It is also more helpful to explain just what is unclear or what additional details are needed, but the standard comment at least indicates that someone thought more was needed.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Yes, But the comment is unclear.  The canned comment should not be used if it is unclear what it means.  That comment is particularly unhelpful and should be deleted. The canned comments should be turned off.  They might be useful on StackOverflow.  They are pretty useless on ELL  Reviewers should write a proper comment (as Marc has done) or say nothing.

Comment: @James K, I do not think it is possible to disable the standard comments for a single site.  You could ask on meta. Absent a clear consensus to forbid their use in a meta discussion, I will not delete such comments, and will decline any flags marking them as "no longer needed" or "unfriendly" Exception, if a post has been edited in response to a comment, a :"no longer needed" flag would perhaps be appropriate. Please do not flag such comments in future unless the post has been so edited.If you wish to post a comment urging people to be more specific from review, feel free.

Comment: I already asked on meta. I will continue to flag comments that seem unfriendly or no longer needed if a comment is unfriendly or no longer needed. I am surprised that you think that comments should not be flagged. In particular, if the comment asks for details and does not indicate what details are needed, (and it would not be reasonable for a reputation 1 user to know what details are needed)  it is unfriendly.  If another comment clarifies the details needed the canned comment is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar is not complex

A pronoun "that" is the subject.  This refers to actions of the textual/spoken context.  The speaker has just "sorted graduation".  They refer to the actions that they have taken as "that".

Then the complement has a passive particle "sorted".

The overall mean could be "We have sorted graduation, and you can see that."

Comment: It might not be obvious to the questioner that _'s_ is the copula "is".

Comment: Am I correct saying it is just a type of grammar called "causative"?

Comment: No.  English forms causative expressions with a verb like "make". :  I made him do it.

Comment: The sentence is "that's graduation sorted," not "that graduation's sorted." The question is why the subject ("that...graduation") appears to be split between the passive auxiliary ("is") and the main verb ("sorted"). To me it just sounds like a mistake.

Comment: It's not a passive auxilliary. It is just the normal linking verb "is"  in an SVC sentence, the only difficulty is the participle "sorted".  You could create similar sentences "That is the apple eaten"